# Firefox columns in css3

Tags: firefox, css

Here is the link to my site that I'm building:

http://joshrcook.com/test

I'm having trouble getting the pictures to touch top and bottom without messing up firefox's columns. I can float the images left, but that seems to break -moz-column-count. Any ideas?

Here is the html for the pictures:

```
<div id="img-wrapper">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <=25; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="photo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/arrow_up_alt1_32x32.png" class="overlay overlay1" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/fullscreen_32x32.png" class="overlay overlay2" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/heart_fill_32x38.png" class="overlay overlay3" /></a>
        <?php echo '<img src="img/tumblr_img_' . $i . '.jpg" class="main_photo" />'; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
 #img-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

.photo {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;

}

.photo a img.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.photo a img.overlay1 {
  left: 25%;
}

.photo a img.overlay2 {
  left: 45%;
}

.photo a img.overlay3 {
  left: 65%;
}

.photo img.main_photo {
  width: 320px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Other than wondering what I'm doing wrong in life after looking at that site, why are you using a vendor-dependent property like `-moz-column-count` (and it's near-contemporaries)? Have you seen [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or any of the other block/responsive libraries that handle this type of thing?

Comment: Yes, I have seen masonry, but I was trying for an all CSS3 solution.  This was just for a personal proof of concept, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.photo {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  margin-bottom: -5pt;
}
```

The above seems to work great in Chrome (release) and IE9. I don't have other browsers to test with on this machine, but I'd start there.

Also possibly it could be because of how the browsers are interpreting your whitespace (margins/padding all look like they're set at 0, so the problem *shouldn't* be there. Try eliminating whitespace within every `<div class="photo"></div>` and see what that does.

Comment: That's great that I can pull the margin up by 5px and make it work, I just don't understand why I have to do that.  It doesn't seem like I should have to...

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the whitespace? I can't tell you how many headaches I've had over browsers doing unexpected things because there was a space, tab, or newline between tags.

Comment: Yeah I eliminated all the whitespace.  I went so far as to put everything on one line and it still didn't seem to fix it... I just can't figure out why it's there.  Oh well, I guess as long as it's fixed, that's what really matters.

Comment: Just a note... I used `pt` instead of `px` because the pixel distances were different between Chrome (6px) and IE (7px), but the `pt` distance was constant... Now that I'm home and have access to Firefox, I see that this remains the case (the gap is 7px, but 5pt)... Just something to keep in mind in case you make any changes and have to adjust that number.